# Change value while program is runing

Tags: python

I need a program on raspberry pi, in which I can change the value of a variable  `delay` while the program is running and is not interrupted by any `input()`. I came up with only one solution: read a value from a text file and change it using another program. But my solution doesn't work very well... When I overwrite a value in a text file, sometimes it happens that the program can't convert it to a float... sometimes it works well and sometimes it prints this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

But the value in the text file seems to be fine...

So, this is main program:

```py
def pause():
    file = open('delay.txt', 'r')
    pause = file.readline()
    return pause
    
delay = float(pause())

while True:
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
    delay = float(pause())
    sleep(delay)
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)
    delay = float(pause())
    sleep(delay)
```

And this is the program, which is changing value in the text file:

```
while True:
    rpm = float(input('RPM: '))

    delay = (1/(rpm*60))/800
    file = open('delay.txt', 'w')
    file.write(str(delay))
      
    file.close()
```

I really can't move with this... I'll be grateful for any advice and help in solving it.
You don't have to stick to my idea with a text file, maybe there is a better solution, but I couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: The best solution would probably be to add some error handling to use the previous value whenever the last value is invalid.

Comment: You should also close files when you are done reading them

Comment: At the time you open the file with `w` the file is truncated and has zero length. If the read comes in before the file is extended, this may be the point at which the read returns an empty string. You are facing a race condition here: the file is read by one process while being modified by another. It may help to use file locking to avoid this. There are modules like `flock` or `fcntl` to do that.

Comment: There are better mechanisms for IPC. One obvious fix would be to change your program so it accepts a signal, and only rereads the file when you send that signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use threading for this. I've made a small code example for you to get you started:

```py
import threading
from time import sleep
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename="thread_output.txt", format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s')

running = True
delay = 1

def worker(delay, running):
  while running():
    logging.debug(1)
    sleep(delay())
    logging.debug(0)
    sleep(delay())

x = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(lambda: delay, lambda: running))
x.start()

while running:
    code = input("""
    Make a choice:
      1) Set delay
      2) quit
    """)
    code = int(code)
    if code == 1:
        try:
            val = input("Give up the desired delay between 0 and 10 seconds:")
            val = int(val)
            assert val >= 0 and val <= 10 
            delay = val
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input! Returning to home menu")
            continue
    elif code == 2:
        running = False
    else:
        print("invalid option! Returning to home menu")
        continue

print("quiting...")
x.join()
```

The part that helps you here is the fact that you pass the value of delay (and in the example also of running) as a lambda function. This means that every time the value is used, the value refetched. If you then were to change the value of the variable, it would get passed on :)

Hit me up if you have more questions!

Comment: Thank you very much! :) 
I didn't know about threading, so I had to learn it yesterday :D
But it works as I wanted :D thx again